# I can't access the file

Tags: python, file

i started with two line code but when i run it keeps crashing and i don't know how to fix it.
The programming language I am using is python
[image]

Comment: Escape the backslashes: "D:\\files\\baitap.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Daniel Said should work but you can also use this:

import os

```
  import os
  pwd = os.getcwd()
  file = open(pwd + "\\filepathhere.filetype")
```

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter understands `\f` and `\b` as some special characters, that is why they are highlighted, you must escape backslashes like so: `"D:\\files\\baitap.txt"` or using a raw string `r"D:\files\baitap.txt"`